# How to handle SMS send errors

Tags: android, error-handling, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that sends SMS msg. 
I want my app to handle the error (if occurred), but i cant throw an exception from the broadcast receiver.

```
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: 
                    //throw new SendSmsException();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                    break;
            }
        }
    },
    new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

How to notify the class/method that requested the SMS send that an error occurred?

Comment: the feasible solution is to send another SMS to client notifying him that error has occurred.Another solution is to use GCM kind of push notification which requires internet connection to send a notification  to client.

Comment: I think i didnt write it well, i mean the client is the class/method that initiated the send SMS.

Comment: You can simple add a Toast to notice user there's error.

Comment: I want the class that requested the SMS to decide what to do. I just need to notify it of the error.

Comment: set a flag in that class and whenever error happens just toggle that flag.Write the code that handles your sms according to that flag. in your class.